# Как уменьшить задержку?

Tags: веб-сервер, клиент-сервер, get

Почему как на локальном сервере, так и на хостинге такая длительная передача файлов? Можно было бы списать на соединение, но канал довольно широкий, а на локальном сервере такого просто не бывает... Учитывая, что всё, кроме 100 кб броузер берёт из кэша. Как решить эту проблему? Никаких директив, кроме RewriteRule в .htaccess не стоит
[image]

Comment: Так может тогда беда не в канале, а в обработке сервера?

Comment: Сравните с пингами сначала.

Comment: @AlexWindHope Спасибо за развёрнутое пояснение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно у вас фронт-енд апач и он загибается. Если у вас фронт-енд еще не nginx - исправьте это. Также можно разбить всю статику на несколько поддоменов. Ну и порешать что-то с этой страшной ересью, а именно - 100500 файлов, слейте весь JS и CSS в 2 файла.

К тому же 304 !== нет запроса на сервер, установите expires header, что-бы браузер действительно брал информацию из кеша напрямую (вообще не делая запроса на сервер).

Также можно настроить gzip сжатие.